# Swift 4 iOS Socket Client

Tags: ios, swift, tcpclient, xcode9

I'm a Swift newbie and I have to connect a iOS mobile to a TCP server based on python. I found some possibilities in my search on the net, but I haven't found an example so far where I can work in xcode 9.

Which is the best library to write an iOS TCP client? 
Are there xcode 9 examples?

Many thx.

Comment: Actually you don't need a library. Please read [Stream Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html)

Comment: Thanks Vadian. Why do you prefer Cocoa stream? I find only very dry Apple theory, but unfortunately no examples!? Can you help me?